# Convert byte array information coming from db2 queries using python

Tags: python, sql, arrays, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am using an iSeries Access ODBC Driver to try and run queries against DB2 for i. I'd like to make this information coming back more readable. How can I convert the byte array information using python? Example output below:

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM QAAPFILE$") 
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x00C6D2C0>
>>> for row in cursor:
...     print row         


Example Output:
(1, bytearray(b'\xfd@@@@@@@@@'), 1, 1, 8, 9, bytearray(b'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'), bytearray(b'@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'), bytearray(b'\x00<\x02\x82B\x02\x02<\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
Many more rows
```

Comment: You should elaborate on what you want by 'readable'.  Obviously it's going to depend on the content of the bytearrays and how they should be interpreted.

Comment: I am hoping to convert the retrieved byte array information into alphanumeric characters (English + Numbers). I have no idea what is stored in these tables and need to figure out what everything is.

Comment: Well the thing in your example is that you're already looking at the data interpreted as single byte characters, and it doesn't look like English strings to me.  Could the data be multi-byte unicode?  You should ask whoever wrote the data into the table how to interpret it.

Comment: The information is retrieved from a db2 on an AS/400 (iSeries) machine. The information stored in these tables is inventory information. I don't know if it is multi-byte information. I need help which is why I came here.

Comment: There is only one way for you. Go to the owner/developer of the application that writes these tables. If there are no developers and/or documentation available, you need to re-engineer the writing app. Long story short, we can't help you with interpreting the data.

Comment: The file `QAAPFILE$` contains the symbol set for small symbol definitions, it's related to [PFD definitions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/books/5445349219.htm). Your inventory information should not be stored in `QGPL` (which is where the `QAAPFILE$` table is located.

Comment: By convention, any object name that starts with a 'Q' is an IBM created object.  This is an obscure system file, for an old print utility, and will tell you *nothing* about inventory.  Get some guidance from your IT department.

Comment: When you do find out what tables (files) in what schemas (libraries) you should be looking at, try using IBM Data Studio, IBM i Access for Windows Navigator, or something like SQL Squirrel to look at the database.  And use the [IBM i Information Center SQL reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintro.htm) to give you just the data you need.  Connect with "system naming" in your connection string, to enable use of the "library list" search path, so that you don't hard-code schema names in your Python or SQL code.

Comment: +1 @WarrenT: I am using SQL Squirrel now so it's not just guesswork to uncover table information.

Comment: So guys ( @Benny Hill ) now that I am in the QS36F database I still don't know where inventory/employee data is located. Files or hard data. My comment to the answer below contains more information. Thanks again!

Comment: The `QS36F` database is System 36 data - just what version of DB2 for i are you working with? To find out where the data your looking for resides you're going to have to ask someone in the organization, none of us can answer that for you.

Comment: Unless you were told to look in QS36F, you are not likely to find it there. I suggest looking in the catalog views such as SYSTABLES. Every IBM i object has a 50 character description attribute field, and most shops use this feature, so look at the TABLE_TEXT in SYSTABLES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're looking at QAAPFILE$, and I'm not sure the data retrieved from it *must* be retrieved as `bytearray`.  But if you absolutely must read raw bytes, then the first thing you need to know is that the IBM i (AS/400, iSeries, etc.) is natively EBCDIC. The '@' is a telltale sign that you need to use `decode('cp037')`.  In code page 37 (standard American EBCDIC, you may need to adjust slightly for different locales), a space is '\x40', which happens to be the same as '@' in ASCII or UTF-8.

Now, I will say that the samples you've given don't decode nicely, so there's unfortunately more to the story.  Like the commenters, I'll need more information.  (For example, still really mystified why you'd need to look at QAAPFILE$.  And, for the record, I have never seen or used that file.  I have used pyODBC plenty of times to connect to the i, and I've never had to use `bytearray`.)

**Edit:** I've now had a chance to look at QAAPFILE$ on the machine where I work, and I can tell you that you're not going to find readable alphanumeric characters in it.  Well, that second column (the first `bytearray` element in the row tuple) is actually readable with the proper decoding, but the last one really isn't, not even looking at it directly on the server using a native interface.  It really is just binary data.  I can't imagine what use you could have for this file.

Comment: I was just using that query as an example. I am now using DB QS36F but still confused where I can find actual inventory/employee data that I need. The best I can do is setup queries through the emulator and read those real time queries in QS36F. Can you give me any more breadcrumbs? Thanks for the decode('cp037') tip, it helps a lot!